# Laravel rename migration class

Tags: laravel

I've recently included a package that has the same migration class name in a migration file:

```php
class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
```

Now I'm wondering if I can safely rename the class name of my own existing migration (that already ran). Will that create issues in the future? I've already renamed the table and updated that using `protected $table` on the model so that's all fine, just wondering about the class name in the migration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this should be no problem at all.

Laravel identifies the migrations from its filename, instead of its containing class(es). You can have a look at the migrations table of your database.

This is also the reason why a migration file consists of the current date.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no problem if you keep 2 classes with same name **while** they are not at the same **Namespace**

but if you want to **rename the migration** then you have to **take care of two things**:

1. ***first rename the filename***
2. ***open that migration file and rename the Class name also***

Renaming the file :
change your filename from `2019_06_28_131130_create_organisations_table` to `2019_06_28_131130_create_organizations_table` or whatever name you want.

**Open that migration file and Rename the class name in that file** as per your new name:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

//change it from
//class CreateOrganisationsTable extends Migration {
//to
class CreateOrganizationsTable extends Migration {
```